# Access Tables vs SharePoint List design

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have moved tables in a DB to SharePoint and the forms, reports etc all display the correct information. The problem is that when I go to add data in a form, I get the "This Recordset is not updateable." notification.
I have attempted researching the issue on line, but none of the solutions that I can get my head around have worked.
I suspect, but can't confirm, it is related to the Keys used in the Access Tables, noting they are different to that used by the SP list.
I have uploaded a defn of one of the tables - one from the SP list and the other from the Access table.
As best as I can tell there is nothing I can do about the SP List using an Autonumber ID as the Key, but there seems to be some work arounds at the client end that can be utilised, but I am not having any joy with that.
Interestingly, the Relationship Diagram had no links showing when I opened the SP version in Access, so I tried creating relationships between the tables using the SP provided ID, but again with no joy.
I CAN edit the tables directly, and effect changes in the SP lists that way, so I do have write permission to the SP Lists.

Any ideas?

Access Table Definitions

[image: Access Table Definitions]

SharePoint Table Definitions

[image: SharePoint Table Definitions]

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome the problem, but it took some work. Basically I had to recreate the queries and the forms using the SP linked tables. I also removed a calculated field, purely because there is a lot of discussion on the problems calculated fields can have with SP linked tables.
There may have been an easier way, but the time it took to rebuild the DB was less that all the time I have spent researching the problem.